# How to reorder form fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP page with a form like this:

```
<form class="form3">
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Item-1</label>
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Item-2</label>
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Item-3</label>
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Item-4</label>
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Item-5</label>
</form>
```

I have javascript variables set like this:

```
var checked = ["", "yes", "", "yes", ""];
```

Now when the page is loaded, I want to check if the the checked value is "yes" then I want to put those input items first in teh list and the remaining ones later, like this:

```
<form class="form3">
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Item-2</label>
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Item-4</label>
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Item-1</label>
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Item-3</label>
<label class="form3"><input type="checkbox"> Item-5</label>
</form>
```

I assume, jQuery would be the way to do it.
which means, I will need to loop through the form fields (which I am not sure how) and inside the loop check if the corresponding variable is blank or 'yes', and if yes, print that form field. Then again go through the same loop and print all fields where corresponding variable is blank.

Hope the logic is correct.

I am able to loop through the form elements like this:

```
$.each($('.form3'),function(i,e){
    if(checked[i] == "")
        {
            e.appendTo($('.form3'));
        }
});
```

BUT
obviously, the appendTo line gives me error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLabelElement> has no method 'appendTo'
```

So, now I would need to know how to pick each one of the rows and reorder them while looping.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us what i and e are?

Comment: i is the index number. e selected the <label> element...... I have edited the code above by adding the correct class name to the form element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('.form3').each(function(i,e) {

    if(checked[i] == "") {

        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);
        $(this).appendTo($('form'));

    }

});
```

Comment: When I try $(this) I get this error: ------------------ Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

Comment: I added this code to make the selected checkboxes 'checked':  -------- $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true);

Comment: @ssdesign okay cool, glad that i could help. Will add it to the answer so others can read it:)

Answer (score 0):

you are thinking in the right direction
here is how i would take care of this:

```
$('.form3').each(function(){
    var lbl = $(this);
    var chk = lbl.find('input[type=checkbox]');
    if(chk.attr('checked'))
    {
        lbl.prependTo($('#myForm'));
    }
});
```

you can find a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/saelfaer/LbMQG/1/

Comment: This one may lead somewhere, but your suggestion assumes that the items have been checked already. I need to check with a javascript array and see if the corresponding array value says "yes", then move that item up. I am trying my best to reuse parts of your code and see if it may lead me somewhere....

Comment: As you can see that I need to add the "checked" attribute if the array value is 'yes'.

Comment: as the other example already fixed your problem i will not bother changing mine as it would involve copying exactly what he did :P

Comment: Thanks for coming forward to help. Appreciate.